# Page Unload Event Works in FireFox Not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following event in JavaScript for page load.whenever the page is closed the alert will show.It will works fine in FireFox but not in Chrome  .How to change this following event common for **IE , FireFox And Chrome**?

```
$(window).unload(function()
{
 alert('Bye')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JS code for a while, this is a bug of JQuery in latest Chrome release.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "to be alerted text"; }
```

Comment: Worked in my chrome, check your chrome release. Update it.